# Service records for wide area Bonjour

Tags: macos, bonjour

I'm trying to figure out how to create service records for wide area bonjour. I haven't been able to find any good documentation on this. Can any point me to some?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation at http://dns-sd.org/:

- [Manually Adding DNS-SD Service Discovery Records to an Existing Name Server](http://www.dns-sd.org/ServerStaticSetup.html)